# Is there a way to unassociate a One Note Notebook from its Skydrive location?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, onedrive

I have a One Note Notebook that I had stored on Web / Skydrive location. But now due to various reasons, I want to unassociate the notebook from my Skydrive and store it on the local machine / on "My computer".

How do I achieve this?

(This is on One Note 2010, Windows 7)

EDIT: More details on how this storing online was achieved:

- No Skydrive was installed
- The notebook had been initially created using "Store Notebook on - My Computer" option under File > New
- Later I stored this online using "Share on Web or Network" option visible under the Notebook item in File > Info panel
- This seems to be the same workflow as "Share on Web" which stores the notebook on a Web Location in Microsoft Skydrive.
- I want to dissociate the notebook for this Sharing/Storing on the Web.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the properties of the notebook
2. Click on 'change location' button, and then change the location to point to a local folder. OneNote will handle the syncup.

Detailed steps here: [Setup onenote on Skydrive](http://www.technlg.net/windows/store-onenote-files-skydrive/)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve my problem by creating another notebook locally and dragging sections manually across, then deleting the old notebook. For some reason when I had tried this method before, the syncing kept failing and the location would not change. However, I tried this again on a test notebook and it worked. So, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is uninstall the sky drive app from the control panel. Reboot your notebook. If you files are still there in the sky drive folder, then delete them. Sky drive will no long update on the notebook in you uninstall it.

Here is a [link](http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-uninstall-skydrive/) to help you.

Comment: Hmm, there is no Sky Drive App in my Control Panel - Like I have already stated, I'm wondering how to do this with Windows 7 and OneNote 2010.

Comment: @Shisa I am not sure I understand your question then. "Like I have already stated, I'm wondering how to do this with Windows 7 and OneNote 2010" In your question you are asking how to "unassociate the notebook from my Skydrive" is that not right?

Comment: @Shisa I am going to update my answer

Comment: Ok, to be clear: I do not have Skydrive installed. The Notebook has been stored online using the "Connect to Windows Live" functionality in OneNote and hence found in that particular Skydrive account. I did not to download anything to my comp to be able to save the notebook on the web. And since I do not have anything Skydrive installed on my comp, it is not possible for me to uninstall it. Thanks.

Comment: Adding more detail to my question

Answer (score 0):

To remove your email account which is saved for ONENOTE 2010.

I am using windows 7.  close all running applications including browser/onenote

1. go to control panel
2. user accounts and family safety
3. credential manager
4. under generic credential, just remove from vault all SAVED accounts/passwords.

EASY...hope this helps.

Comment: This question was answered nearly 3 years ago. Try to answer newer questions for a better likelihood of earning reputation.